# Meaning of 3/4 broken circle icon?

Tags: samsung, notification-icons

I got a strange icon I've never seen before on my Samsung A3. It's in the top left corner, shaped like an 'o' letter, but with the top right quarter of the circle broken. Its not a sync icon (that has arrows and it's broken in two halves). Does anybody know what it means? I could not find it anywhere on the web. In the notification swipe screen there is nothing that points at its meaning.

See answer